# Zurb Foundation Orbit slider: crop image to fit window

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm using foundation and I want to use orbit as a full width slideshow. I need it to cover the whole window, width and height.

It seems the default usage of this slider is simply to adapt the width of the images to the container but I need it to fit the height, cropping the image if needed to keep the ratio. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting a min-height on the container, and an overflow:hidden;  to "crop" the image to the exact height?

Your image height would have to be equal to or greater than your min-height.

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:hidden"> 
   <img src="image" style="width:100%" alt="always use alts" /> 
</div>
```